# flaskwebgui address "refused to connect" + missing 'environ' and 'start_response'

Tags: python, linux, flask, chromium

I have a basic flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask
import flaskwebgui

app = Flask(__name__)
gui = flaskwebgui.FlaskUI(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui.run()
```

Using `app.run()` instead of `gui.run()` works as expected. No errors and I get a localhost link that I can click to view the site.

However, if I do what I did in the example above, I get this for my output:

```
path to chrome not found
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
Command: python3 -m webbrowser -n http://127.0.0.1:33951
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: Flask.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'
```

I managed to resolve the first error by downloading a chromium AppImage and modifying the FlaskUI to:

```
gui = flaskwebgui.FlaskUI(app, browser_path="./chrome.AppImage")
```

Now, this is the output:

```
ofstuff/b0unce¡t/app.py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
Command: ./chrome.AppImage --user-data-dir=/tmp/flaskwebgui --new-window --no-first-run --start-maximized --app=http://127.0.0.1:40077
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: Flask.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/simon/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
Gtk-Message: 14:36:18.659: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 14:36:18.662: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[24939:24939:0919/143618.957750:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(154)] :components/enterprise/browser/controller/chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[24939:24939:0919/143619.954445:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service files
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

A chrome window without tabs opens as I would expect it to, but it can't find the address: `127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`

I am in a python venv in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 22.04.03

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding app=app and server="flask" as parameters when initializing FlaskUI.

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskwebgui import FlaskUI

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FlaskUI(app=app, server="flask", width=800, height=600).run()
```